# Unable to locate private key (file/directory not found) when authenticating with Google BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to read records from a table in Google BigQuery to my notebook. I run the following script to establish the connection with **my private key stored locally on my machine**. I've ensured that I set the service account up correctly via the GCS UI with the correct permissions (BQ Owner - Does it need to be admin?).

Block 1

```
import sys
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import language
import pandas_gbq as pd
```

Block 2

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
'/Users/alh/Downloads/transcript_test.json')

project_id = 'dgi-prd'
client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)
```

I receive the following error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-e867ba05be00> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
      2 '/Users/alh/Downloads/transcript_test.json')
      3 
      4 project_id = 'dgi-prd'
      5 client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py in from_filename(filename, require, use_rsa_signer)
     78             info and a signer instance.
     79     """
---> 80     with io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
     81         data = json.load(json_file)
     82         return data, from_dict(data, require=require, use_rsa_signer=use_rsa_signer)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/alh/Downloads/transcript_test.json'
```

This seems to be a pretty straightforward behavior so wondering if there's an issue with my environment thats not allowing my local key to be read?

Comment: This is very likely a wrong filepath. The last message tells you, that the file under that path doesn't exist.
What do you get if you write `ls /Users/alh/Downloads/transcript_test.json` in a terminal?

Comment: alh@A11565 ~ % ls /Users/alh/Downloads/transcript_test.json /Users/alh/Downloads/transcript_test.json alh@A11565 ~ %

Comment: Does this code run directly on your computer?  Or does it run inside a docker container or virtual environment?

Comment: no docker container and I ran `import sys
sys.prefix == sys.base_prefix` which returned `True` so no virtual env.

Comment: I was able to figure out I was in the wrong directory by running `import os

cwd = os.getcwd()  # Get the current working directory (cwd)
files = os.listdir(cwd)  # Get all the files in that directory
print("Files in %r: %s" % (cwd, files))`

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed venv was in the wrong directory by runnning

```
cwd = os.getcwd()  # Get the current working directory (cwd)
files = os.listdir(cwd)  # Get all the files in that directory
print("Files in %r: %s" % (cwd, files))
```